# Discard partial timeperiods when downsampling in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

**TLDR: When downsampling a Series with a `DatetimeIndex`, e.g. from hourly to daily values, how can I ensure the result only contains time periods that are fully present in the original?**

## Example

I'll explain with a simplified example.

#### Starting point: daily values

```py
import pandas as pd

# Source data: 2 full days, AND SOME ADDITIONAL HOURS.
i = pd.date_range('2022-03-04 22:00', '2022-03-07 09:00', freq='H')
hourly = pd.Series(range(len(i)), i)
```

I want to resample to days, but keep only those that days are *completely* present in the source series.

#### What is working: calendar days

If a day is defined as a normal calendar day, i.e., midnight to midnight, we can do this in 2 steps:

```py
# 1) Resample.
grouper = pd.Grouper(freq='D')
daily = hourly.groupby(grouper).sum() # or .resample('D').sum()
# 2022-03-04      1
# 2022-03-05    324
# 2022-03-06    900
# 2022-03-07    545
# Freq: D, dtype: int64

# 2) Discard incomplete days.
# (reject the days that start before the start of the first hour)
incomplete_left = daily.index < hourly.index[0]
# (reject the days that end after the end of the last hour)
incomplete_right = daily.index + pd.offsets.Day(1) > hourly.index[-1] + pd.offsets.Hour(1)
# Trim.
daily_trimmed = daily[~incomplete_left & ~incomplete_right] # Keeps 2022-03-05 and -06. Good.
# 2022-03-05    324
# 2022-03-06    900
# Freq: D, dtype: int64
```

Sofar, so good.

#### What is not working: custom starting point

But what if a day is defined as starting at 06:00 and ending at 06:00 the next calender day? **I can do the resampling, but don't know how to check which timestamps to reject.**

```py
# 1) Resampling is doable:
import datetime
def gasday(ts: pd.Timestamp) -> pd.Timestamp:
    day = ts.floor("D")
    if ts.time() < datetime.time(hour=6):  
        day = day - pd.DateOffset(days=1) # get previous day
    return day

daily2 = hourly.groupby(gasday).sum()
# 2022-03-04      28
# 2022-03-05     468
# 2022-03-06    1044
# 2022-03-07     230
# dtype: int64

# 2) ... but how to find the days that must be rejected??
```

## Remarks

- I'm using `DatetimeIndex`, instead of `PeriodIndex`, which is why I we have the somewhat complicated formula for `incomplete_right`. The reason for using `DatetimeIndex` is that I'm generally dealing with timezones (not shown in this example). The timestamps in the datetimeindex are left-bound.
- In my use-case, I'm given the `grouper` function (`gasday` in this case), without knowing, what the cutoff time is (06:00 in this case).

Answer (score 0):

If your data is guaranteed to be hourly, then you can just count the records:

```
daily = hourly.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D', offset='6H')).agg(['size','sum'])
```

Output:

```
                     size   sum
2022-03-04 06:00:00     8    28
2022-03-05 06:00:00    24   468
2022-03-06 06:00:00    24  1044
2022-03-07 06:00:00     4   230
```

Looking form the data, it's fairly easy to see which ones should be dropped

```
complete_daily = daily.query('size==24')
```

Output:

```
                     size   sum
2022-03-05 06:00:00    24   468
2022-03-06 06:00:00    24  1044
```

**Update**: You can also try:

```
daily = (hourly.reset_index().groupby(pd.Grouper(key='index', freq='D', offset='6H'))
               .agg(start=('index','min'), end=('index','max'), total=(0,'sum'))
        )
```

Output:

```
                                  start                 end  total
index                                                             
2022-03-04 06:00:00 2022-03-04 22:00:00 2022-03-05 05:00:00     28
2022-03-05 06:00:00 2022-03-05 06:00:00 2022-03-06 05:00:00    468
2022-03-06 06:00:00 2022-03-06 06:00:00 2022-03-07 05:00:00   1044
2022-03-07 06:00:00 2022-03-07 06:00:00 2022-03-07 09:00:00    230
```

You can then query for complete days, e.g.

```
daily['start'].dt.hour.eq(6) & daily['end'].dt.hour.eq(5)
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for that! However, due to DST, not all days have 24 hours - some have 23 and some have 25. The same goes when upsampling from days to months for example (I didn't explicitly mention that; my bad).

Comment: Then you can reset the data, aggregate min/max on the index and check if they matches the beginning/end of the periods.

Comment: What do you mean with 'reset the data'? Could you include an example it in your answer?

Comment: I mean reset index of the data, so you can aggregate on the index as well. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I'll see if I can adjust it to use the `gasday` grouper, because shifting everything by 6h as you've done here goes wrong at the DST transitions - 06:00 is usually 6h past midnight, but on the start of DST it is only 5h and at the end it is 7h. But it's a good start - I'll let you know if I got it to work!

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to use the following logic:

- If the first timestamp in `hourly.index` belongs to the same group (= same day) as the timestamp immediately before it, then the group is not fully present in the `hourly` series and the first datapoint in `daily` must be removed. If it does not belong to the same group, it is really the start of a new group, the group is fully present in `hourly`, and no change is needed to `daily`.
- Likewise, if the **end** of the last timestamp in `hourly.index` belongs to the same day as the timestamp immediately before* it, then the group is also not fully present in the `hourly` series, and the final datapoint in `daily` must be removed.

```py
eps = pd.Timedelta(seconds=1)
start = hourly.index[0]
if gasday(start) == gasday(start - eps):
    daily2 = daily2.iloc[1:]
end = hourly.index[-1] + pd.offsets.Hour(1)
if gasday(end - eps) == gasday(end):
    daily2 = daily2.iloc[:-1]
```

This works, and keeps the two days (2022-03-05 and -06) as wanted. It includes (-04) if we start `i` at `2022-03-04 06:00` or earlier. Likewise, it keeps (-06) only if we end `i` at `2022-03-07 05:00` or later.

*) Why before? Well, the `05:00` timestamp denotes the left-closed interval `[05:00-06:00)`. 06:00 is actually the start of the next hour. Therefor, if this 06:00 timestamp belongs to the same day, as the moment immediately before it (05:59:59), then we do not have the complete day.

---

---

---

Now the only issues I have left is the following: I'd like to abstract this all away, like so:

```py
def resample_and_trim(source, grouper):
    agg = source.groupby(grouper).sum()

    eps = pd.Timedelta(seconds=1)
    start = source.index[0]
    if grouper(start) == grouper(start - eps):
        agg = agg.iloc[1:]
    end = source.index[-1] + pd.offsets.Hour(1)
    if grouper(end - eps) == grouper(end):
        agg = agg.iloc[:-1]
    return agg
```

And then be able to call this in both cases. The latter works:

```py
daily2 = resample_and_trim(hourly, gasday)
# 2022-03-05     468
# 2022-03-06    1044
# dtype: int64
```

But the former does not:

```py
daily = resample_and_trim(hourly, pd.Grouper(freq='H'))
# Error in `grouper(start)`
# TypeError: 'TimeGrouper' object is not callable
```

I'll doctor around a bit more; if I find the solution, I'll edit this answer.